# Selecting from array of id's via includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Not sure how to fix an issue I'm having with selecting an individual
id from an array.

I have a model for stores, products, and prices. Stores have many
(has_many) products, and products have one (has_one) price per store.
I'm seeding the DB with CSV data. My app primarily functions as an API only.

Prices.csv (where products with ids: 7 and 8 both share the same price
of $4.25 in store 3):

```
amount,product_id,store_id
"3.49","{6}","3"
"4.25","{7,8}","3"
```

create_prices.rb:

```
create_table :prices do |t|
...
     t.integer :product_id, array: true, default: []
... etc
end
```

The problem comes in my query when I attempt to include the price
association, I get an error stating:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
(PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] =
integer LINE 1: ...LEFT OUTER JOIN "prices" ON "prices"."product_id" =
"product...
```

I believe the problem has something to do with the includes for prices not being formatted properly to handle the array?

Products Controller:

```
class API::ProductsController < ApplicationController
@products = Product.where("products.store_id @> '{?}'", params[:id].to_i).includes(:price).where('prices.store_id = ?', params[:id]).references(:prices).limit(params[:max])
end
```

Product.rb model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
  has_one :price

def as_json(options)
    super(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :image, :weight, :store_id],
      :include => {
            :price => {:only => [:amount, :store_id]}
          }
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Only use quote formatting for content you are copying from some other source. If you are quoting someone you need to provide appropriate attribute information.

Comment: @theTinMan Oops, I've now removed the quote formatting

Comment: I don't think believe associations support the use of array columns like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an array data type for prices product_id, just use an integer and have a separate record for each store/product combo

Then try using has_one through for price

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  has_one :price, through: :store
```

In your controller try preloads instead of includes, this should generate 2 queries, one for products and one for prices with the correct where clause

```
@products = Product.where(store_id: params[:id]).preload(:price)
```